# Is there a reliable way to determine if a URL returns content or an error?

Tags: http-headers, web-services

I've got a business requirement to run through a list of URLs and identify the ones that return an error. I've written a simple script that fetches the header for a particular url since I don't care about the content. I just want to know if there's an error fetching the content. In some cases, my script returns a 503 error while also returning content. Here's one example.

```
$ curl --head https://www.eia.gov/consumption/
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 175
Expires: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 21:32:47 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 21:32:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Running the same curl command without the "--head" part returns a page of HTML and it's not an error page. It's relevant content. So, that 503 error is misleading.

Is this a misconfigured web server returning an incorrect response header or am I missing something?

The real question is this: **Is there a reliable way to determine if a URL returns valid content or if it returns an error?** The presence of HTML is useful in this case but I wouldn't count on getting HTML back meaning there is not an error. The 404 error is the classic case of getting a page of HTML but the error code tells me that the page wasn't found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--head` option makes `curl` send an actual `HTTP HEAD` request. Some servers might not honor this or might not route it the same as an `HTTP GET` request such as a browser would send. Using the `-i` option will print response headers but still send a `GET` request. This will also return the entire body of the response. You could cut this down to the first line containing the protocol version and response status only with the `head` command like so:

```
$ curl -si https://www.eia.gov/consumption/ | head -n 1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

(The `-s` option for curl prevents showing the download status triggered by piping curl to another process. `-n` option on head is the number of lines to return.)

How to determine success depends on your definition of "valid". [HTTP standards](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) consider anything in the 200 or 300 range to be successful. If you wanted to detect based on that you could use `grep` like so:

```
$ curl -si https://www.eia.gov/consumption/ | head -n 1 | grep -E 'HTTP/\d\.\d (2|3)\d\d '
```

This uses a regular expression to match on any return code starting with 2 or 3. Make sure you don't try to match on the HTTP protocol version as it may not always be the same.

Once you have the line returned by `curl` and `head`, there is endless possibilities to process, format, and return the results depending on what you actually need.

Comment: Interesting! So, I can't rely on getting the same response header if I do HEAD vs. GET. That's too bad since my preference is not to fetch the page. Is your experience that GET is closer to what a browser does?

Comment: If you enter a URL in a browser it surely does a GET request.